# Adjust the min max values of x-axis to autofit the chart

Tags: charts, zingchart

I am trying to plot a zing chart in angular2. My chart comes out to be like this.
[image]

While I want my chart to look like the one I provided below, so that the min and max values of the x-axis are auto adjusted to fit to the area and horizontal width of the chart.
[image]

How can I go about doing this? I followed these links but could not get the desired results. Could you point where am I going wrong ?
https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/configure-chart-scales/#scale-formatting
The options that I gave to plot the chart as follows:

```
this.charts = [{
          id : 'chart-1',
          data : {
              'type' : 'area',
              'scaleX': {
                'label': {'text': 'Price'}
              },
              'scaleY': {
                'label': {'text': 'Cumulative Volume'}
              },
              'plotarea': {
                'adjust-layout': true /* For automatic margin adjustment. */
              },
              'scale-x': {
                'auto-fit': true,
                'min-value': minValue,
                'max-value': maxValue,
                'decimals': 2

              },
              'series': [
                { 'values': this.bidArray },
                { 'values': this.askArray }
              ],
          },
          height: 300,
          width: 600
      }];
    }
```

Edit 1:
**bidArray** and **askArray** are of the format array of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to set the attribute `auto-fit` true. This is for charts that have zooming applied.

You do not need to set the attributes `min-value` or `max-value` to get the x-axis to fit automatically. It will do this by default.

The problem might lie in the one part of the chart you didn't give any information about. How is your data plotted? What are the value arrays? Array of Arrays?

Post the full chart JSON and I'll get you a demo working. Since your chart is dynamic you can grab the rendering JSON by right clicking on the chart, clicking the **View Source** option, then copying the contents from the **parsed JSON** tab.

EDITED NEW ANSWER IN RESPONSE TO FIRST COMMENT BELOW:

Array of arrays does not automatically fit the graph width on scaleX. The reason for this is you are requesting to plot something much more specific than a single dimensional array. So you are right to set the `minValue` and `maxValue`.

The main issue is the `step` value. Since you have defined a step that is less precise than values in the `minvalue` or `maxvalue` you must make it match the same precision. For example you put two decimals, execpt your step is set to `step:.2` which is only of precision of one decimal. Change that precision to two. `step:.01 || .02` to get the desired results you are looking for.

One quick side note. You have two `scale-x` objects. They get merged internally, but this is dangerous because the lower one will override the first. If you have a large JSON this becomes harder to debug.

[demo link](https://demos.zingchart.com/view/ID0QECQ3)

```js
var myConfig = {
"graphset":[
    {
        "type":"area",
        "title":{
            "text":"Market Depth",
            "font-size":14,
            "offset-x":-200,
            "offset-y":-5
        },
        "scaleY":{
            "label":{
                "text":"Cumulative Volume"
            }
        },
        "plotarea":{
            "adjust-layout":true
        },
        "scale-x":{
            "min-value":10.091,
            "max-value":11.308,
            "step": .01,
            "decimals":2,
            "label":{
                "text":"Price"
            }
        },
        "series":[
            {
                "values":[[10.091,23128.285630000002],
                [10.092,22272.984500000002],
                [10.094,22070.219080000003],
                [10.118,21630.372470000002],
                [10.145,21278.48053],
                [10.169,20438.89872],
                [10.209,19798.506260000002],
                [10.218,19128.53049],
                [10.293,18200.525190000004],
                [10.316,17625.84755],
                [10.341,16860.282690000004],
                [10.352,16752.07929],
                [10.363,15806.925830000002],
                [10.366,15351.489590000001],
                [10.372,15088.74344],
                [10.393,14793.26244],
                [10.401,13968.11667],
                [10.423,13873.98204],
                [10.456,13655.87469],
                [10.476,12866.84064],
                [10.535,12518.24981],
                [10.602,12503.24074],
                [10.623,11940.5453],
                [10.632,11939.08057],
                [10.634,11838.884329999999],
                [10.663,11074.893349999998],
                [10.663,10963.316989999998],
                [10.666,10584.14343],
                [10.667,10358.20835],
                [10.671,9942.126730000002],
                [10.672,9265.449410000001],
                [10.674,8497.838590000001],
                [10.679,7865.162790000001],
                [10.694,7349.383660000001],
                [10.713,6672.761850000002],
                [10.736,6026.31731],
                [10.741,5674.348190000001],
                [10.752,5186.775390000001],
                [10.759,4317.745790000001],
                [10.807,3807.78019],
                [10.827,3638.4528899999996],
                [10.831,2816.4248099999995],
                [10.834,2426.4046799999996],
                [10.854,2423.4017],
                [10.854,2184.2459999999996],
                [10.855,1448.32144],
                [10.856,481.7664500000001],
                [10.865,92.60541],
                [10.87,59.9149],
                [10.874,10.04495]],
                backgroundColor: '#424242',
                alphaArea:.56,
                lineColor: '#424242',
                marker: {
                  backgroundColor:'#424242',
                  visible:true
                }
            },
            {
                "values":[[11.308,26417.464129999997],
                [11.285,26220.324189999996],
                [11.208,25644.388599999995],
                [11.194,25628.031659999997],
                [11.188,25031.713569999996],
                [11.182,24205.770269999997],
                [11.144,23534.17388],
                [11.142,22947.082829999996],
                [11.113,22639.772689999994],
                [11.105,22536.636229999993],
                [11.09,21987.267979999993],
                [11.087,21137.004579999997],
                [11.084,20341.394259999997],
                [11.075,19372.91412],
                [11.074,18554.458],
                [11.064,17632.22014],
                [11.053,17063.184230000003],
                [11.05,16285.860740000004],
                [11.033,15644.169050000006],
                [11.022,15330.170840000004],
                [11.018,14424.291480000005],
                [11.007,13641.930940000004],
                [11.001,12755.045610000003],
                [10.999,12266.619580000002],
                [10.992,12034.113860000001],
                [10.981,11362.05282],
                [10.98,10739.11108],
                [10.977,9945.179989999999],
                [10.976,8958.965719999998],
                [10.974,8579.633059999998],
                [10.972,8124.936529999999],
                [10.966,7918.067119999999],
                [10.964,7038.952039999999],
                [10.962,6756.983329999999],
                [10.96,6028.072429999998],
                [10.955,5516.051169999999],
                [10.946,4738.703779999999],
                [10.943,4436.934409999999],
                [10.941,4417.186269999998],
                [10.94,4120.44594],
                [10.939,3830.56787],
                [10.925,3414.84425],
                [10.923,3335.96724],
                [10.922,3025.91816],
                [10.92,2119.4797900000003],
                [10.908,1469.96346],
                [10.903,1269.4567200000001],
                [10.892,630.18796],
                [10.891,273.01724],
                [10.89,103.07879]],
                backgroundColor: '#c62828',
                alphaArea:.56,
                lineColor: '#c62828',
                marker: {
                  backgroundColor:'#c62828',
                  visible:true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to your instructions I have created a github gist. Thanks a lot for your help. https://gist.github.com/agatsoh/ed10be74f211a1ca6082629975adad33

Comment: Thanks a lot solving this for me. the most important point to note was not to have two scaleX and scale-x objects simultaneously and only to have one scale-x object.